# text and images using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4

I need to make text wrap around image with bootstrap 4 but I cannot find how .

Here my code:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/JgqPv7T.png" style="position: relative; right: 44px;">Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
                </div>
                    </div>
```

Here what I have now: 
[image: Here what I have now:]

Here what I would to have: 
[image: Here what I would to have:]

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve your design html and css. Please check it. Thanks

```css
.img-fluid { position:absolute; left:-20px}
.alert.alert-warning { padding:30px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/JgqPv7T.png">Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
                </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Warning: this solution uses absolute values):

```html
<head>
 <style>
     .content {
         padding-left: 8px;
         margin-top: -35px;
        }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.imgur.com/JgqPv7T.png" style="position: relative; right: 44px; ">
            <p class="content">
Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
   </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```